# Navigation bar overlay color

Tags: android, android-styles, navigationbar

So I have a app, were all screens are full. In fact both status and navigation bars are hidden even on user tap. Now the problem is, there's a black layer at the place of Navigation bar when it's hidden.

[image: Screenshot]

My style is like this

```
<style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

onWindowFocusChanged i'm setting SystemUiVisibility with these

```
int uiOptions =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    findViewById(R.id.rl_main).setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

This is my `.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/rl_main">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried:

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
</style>
```

nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: You have to at least show the xml layout and the activity.onCreate.

Comment: @luiscosta I've added my xml. There's nothing new called in onCreate just setContent and initializing webview.

Comment: Where is your toolbar? :D If you have no toolbar at all why are you hiding it?

Comment: Try adding this to your activity in the Manifest: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: I'm not talking about toolbar. It's soft navigation bar(at bottom with home n recent button) which is causing issues.

Comment: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`
This made the black layer transparent. Since there's not other layer behind it, i can see Android home screen.

Comment: So you need to add this to your base style: `<item name="windowBackground">@color/red</item>`

Comment: I need to fill that space with my xml view. There's no point in showing a different color over there.

Comment: In which device or emulator are you testing?

Comment: @VirajPatel I'm testing on Device (Redmi note 5 Pro).

Comment: I have checked your code in the emulator and it is working fine. Please check it one in the emulator as well as in another device.

Comment: @Shahal maybe i misleading with your title of your question. But i checked your code its working correctly on Android 6.0.1 (Api 23) device...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can FullScreen your Activity

Edit your styles.xml

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#00ffffff</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Comment: what should be the base theme for this?